Conditionally adding a row within a pipe
I have a tibble containing events and their probabilities. The number of outcomes can be two (Yes/No) or greater (A/B/C/...). In the latter case, I have a exhaustive list of events, so I want to do nothing:
ok <- tibble(
    event = c("A", "B", "C"), 
    prob = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.4)
)

If there are only two events, I only have one row, for the probability of the event occurring:
not_ok <- tibble(
    event = "Yes", 
    prob = 0.4
)

These tibbles are modified in a pipe chain. At a precise point, I want to add a row "No" to tibbles of the second type.
Currently, I'm interrupting the pipe to do:
if (nrow(not_ok) == 1) {
    not_ok %<>%
        add_row(event = "No", prob = 1-not_ok$prob)
}

And then I resume the pipe. However doing this is slow, ugly, and requires more assignments.
Is it possible to include this conditional statement inside the pipe chain, without separately creating an if statement? The code in the end should look like:
data %>% 
    do something %>% 
    add row with "No" if necessary %>% 
    do something else %>% 
    plot

If possible, I would like to avoid using global assignments or functions.

For clarity: the data comes from a server request, so I do not know whether a specific requests pulls a tibble of the type ok or not_ok. I need a single operation that works in both cases, by doing nothing in the first case, and adding a row in the second. For example, what I'm doing currently works because I use an if function to only edit not_ok if that's the result of the request. For example:
fread("...") %>% 
    mutate(...) %>% 
    add row if nrow == one


tidyr::expand() or tidyr::complete should do what you want, depending on your exact use case.  All you will need is a vector of all possible events.  Follow with a mutate to derive the left-over probability.  If there's a chance or more than one omitted event type, you'll have to define how to allocate the probabilities.

The problem is how to make this conditional on the number of rows. If it's greater than one, then everything is already fine. If there is one row, that's for "Yes". so I want to add a row for "No".

I am missing something: isn't that exactly what I've done?  or are you saying that order is important, so "add" means "append at the end"?

Sorry, I had not seen your answer. I will reply to it.

Here's a solution using complete:
not_ok %>% 
  complete(
    event = c("Yes", "No"),
    fill = list(prob = (1 - sum(not_ok$prob)))
  )
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  event  prob
  <chr> <dbl>
1 No      0.6
2 Yes     0.4

whereas ok is left unchanged:
ok %>% 
  complete(
    event = c("A", "B", "C"),
    fill = list(prob = (1 - sum(not_ok$prob)))
  )
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  event  prob
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A       0.1
2 B       0.5
3 C       0.4

If your tibble is grouped, or you need more sophisitcated imputation, a minor variation on this should suffice.
Edit
In response to OP's comment, here's how to encapsulate the functionality in a pipe-friendly function.
make_complete <- function(df, event_list) {
  df %>% 
  complete(
    event = event_list,
    fill = list(prob = (1 - sum(df$prob)))
  )
}

After which
not_ok %>% make_complete(c("Yes", "No"))

and
ok %>% make_complete(c("A", "B", "C"))

Both produce the expected output above.  The function can clearly be embedded in a longer pipe.
With regard to your comment "I would like to avoid using ... functions".  I don't see how you can make this generic without using a function...

This works, but perhaps I was not clear about the data. It comes from some function, so call it generically df. I need to make an operation that works for both ok and not_ok, because I do not know which one it is. I will make an edit to the original post.

As I demonstrate, this does work in both cases.  if you want to integrate it in your pipe, encapsulate it in a function whose first parameter is the data frame and the second the complete list of event values.

Thanks for writing the function. The issue was that, since I don't know if my data is ok or not_ok, I do not have an event_list to provide to the function. But the following works: df %>% make_complete(event_list = if(nrow(df) == 1) {c("Yes", "No")} else { df$event }). This works whether df <- ok, by adding a row, or whether df <- not_ok, by doing nothing.

Create an events tibble of all events, eventsdf, join it to not_ok and then use coalesce to fill in the NA, if any.
library(dplyr)
    
f <- function(df, all_events) {
  eventsdf <- tibble(event = all_events)
  df %>%
    right_join(eventsdf, by = "event") %>%
    mutate(prob = coalesce(prob, 1 - sum(prob, na.rm = TRUE)))
}
    
f(not_ok, c("Yes", "No"))
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##   event  prob
##   <chr> <dbl>
## 1 Yes     0.4
## 2 No      0.6

f(ok, c("A", "B", "C"))
## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##   event  prob
##   <chr> <dbl>
## 1 A       0.1
## 2 B       0.5
## 3 C       0.4


Thank you, please see the edit to the original post. This works to modify a not_ok tibble, but the data comes from a request, and may either be ok or not_ok, so I need a conditional statement that works on the latter.

Have revised.  Should now work with both cases.
